# Is there no defense roll for targets at ground zero?

Tags: d6-system, area-of-effect

> The effect of the spell travels out from a target. Add the area effect
>   modifier to the Spell Total.
>   Adjust the effect by -1 (pip, point of damage, etc.) per full meter
>   for characters outside of ground zero (within a half-meter of the
>   target). Compare the targeting roll of spell against the defense total
>   **of characters not at ground zero**; those who have a defense total
>   greater than the targeting roll managed to dive for cover or protect
>   themselves from the effect.

I'm wondering here. Does that mean if I hit the original target. Are there NO defense rolls for all others at ground zero (thus auto hit)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes, there is no defense roll

Don't forget that ground zero has a very strict definition:

> ... ground zero (within a half-meter of the target) ...