# Are there any rules or generally accepted houserules to avoid ground zero exploitation?

Tags: d6-system, area-of-effect

A while ago I asked a question ([Is there no defense roll for targets at ground zero?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/75924/is-there-no-defense-roll-for-targets-at-ground-zero)) about wether the targets who are beside the original target inside an AOE get a defense roll. The answer to that according to the rules was "no".

I'm wondering there now if there are some rules or generally used houserules to avoid exploitation of this. For example if we take the DC universe. Someone sees the Flash just beside Batman and wants to hit him with a grenade. The Flash has quite a high chance of avoiding the hit thanks to his speed but Batman not so. Thus the grenade would be thrown at Batman in order to also hit the Flash (and that automatically).

(I know at least enough players who would do this, and I know how I'd handle it myself through house rules etc, but what interests me is if there is something within the rules that I have overlooked or if there is a general concensus on a specific way to handle this)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ground zero (within a half-meter of the target)

Ground zero is quite a small space. For comparison, two characters standing in melee reach from each other are at Point Blank Range:

> A target within a few steps of the attacker is at Point Blank range.

Point Blank range is considered longer than 0.5m:

> Point Blank 0–3 meters

Most likely there will not be two characters at ground zero unless they are hugging each other.

If they are indeed hugging each other and standing in the same 1 m diameter circle, then it is reasonable that their ability to dodge is compromised (judging by the slower of the two sounds reasonable), since they're not properly preparing to dodge:

> A character who is dodging is anticipating the location of his
>   attacker's aim (before the attack is made), and is doing all he can to
>   maneuver himself out of that area.

Thus, a simple solution to avoid players from exploiting this is that characters who are not for some reason touching each other can be assumed to stand more than 0.5 m from each other (and thus get a chance to defend).

Comment: still though also 2 soldiers standing side by side in a roman legions formation would also fit the bill of both being at ground zero wouldnt they=

Comment: Yes they would, just standing there. But are they still in formation if they are attempting to dodge the grenade? It seems strange that they would dive for cover and stay in formation doing it. If they decide to stay in formation, then both should be hit if one are.

Comment: It is an explanation on the original rule which in my mind sorts out the situation. Judging from the down-votes others do not share in this perception, but this part of the OP ("For example if we take the DC universe. Someone sees the Flash just beside Batman and wants to hit him with a grenade.)" fits well with my answer that "just beside" is more than 0.5 m and thus the original rule apply.

Comment: I added quotes to support my conclusion.

Comment: The quotes not only give more support, but they also explain better what point this answer is making. Nice! I've taken the liberty of moving the quotes up into the parts of the post that they are supporting. (Posts should be written as if they are complete, and [not contain notes or marks showing that they've been changed](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3454/dont-signal-your-edits-in-text).)